# Sequence without the row number

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have below data set

```
Create table #table(
Message varchar(10),
ID varchar(5),
ParentID varchar(5))


Insert into #table 
select 'Parent','123',''
UNION
select 'Child','234','123'
UNION
select 'Child','345','123'
UNION
select 'Child','145','123'
UNION
select 'Parent','333',''
UNION
select 'Child','567','333'
UNION
select 'Child','789','333'
UNION
select 'Child','100','333'
UNION
select 'Child','111','333'

select * from #table
```

when I select the data , data looks random. but i would like to have in below sequence

```
Message    ID      ParentID
Parent     123     
Child      234     123
Child      345     123
Child      145     123 
Parent     333     
Child      567     333
Child      789     333
Child      100     333 
Child      111     333
```

I tried with row number , it is not working somehow for the below sequence. 
Can someone please help me ?

Comment: Why would it show in a particular order? You don't have an `ORDER BY` clause. Tables are store in **unordered** heaps; if you want the returned dataset to be in specific order, you need to tell the Data engine what that order is.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57497176/6167855

Comment: yeah.. i tried with order by as well. but i am not getting in this sequence.

Comment: Why the varchar on the IDs? Shoudln't those be INT?

Comment: no actual Id's are different.. they have alphanumeric fields.

Comment: Then give representative examples @chits. Numerics and strings sort *very* differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `CASE` statement in `ORDER BY`, The following query should do what you want:

```
select * from #table
order by case when Message = 'Parent' then ID else ParentID end, ParentID
```

Comment: @chits so all your messages's content is 'Parent'?

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
select message,id,parentid
from  #table
order by case when parentid = '' then convert(int,id)-1 else parentid end
```

this solution is not based of message column and will correct with all data sets.

Comment: thanks, this works.. but my ID  cannot be converted to int. Its alphanumeric value..

Answer (score 0):

Use conditional sorting:

```
select * from #table
order by case when parentid = '' then id else parentid end, parentid
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=052ced1a6f4b4114c267c967b826bfab).
Results:

```
> Message | ID  | ParentID
> :------ | :-- | :-------
> Parent  | 123 |         
> Child   | 145 | 123     
> Child   | 234 | 123     
> Child   | 345 | 123     
> Parent  | 333 |         
> Child   | 100 | 333     
> Child   | 111 | 333     
> Child   | 567 | 333     
> Child   | 789 | 333
```

If the parents contain `NULL` at the `parentid` column instead of `''`, then the `ORDER BY` clause must be changed to:

```
order by isnull(parentid, id), parentid
```

Comment: if i convert to Null it works fine.. thank you guys. but the system doesnt accept the null values. it is expecting blanks only.

Comment: You can see in the demo that the 1st query works with blanks.